# AJAX updating variables in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, ejs

I am trying using ajax for the first time. I have a working site and want to make it improve, therefore I dont want to redirect the clients on each post, I want to use AJAX and do a databse call in the backend with node.js.

For HTML I am using EJS. I want to let AJAX get called when the page is loaded. All that is already working.

My problem is, that I am using an if call in EJS.

its like:

```
if(variableX === 0){
render this header
} else{
render login header with name
}
```

The function in the backend gets called, but its not going to render the variables in my EJS file.

Can anyone help?

EJS:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: '/',
             dataType: 'text',
             async: false
         })
  });
  </script>  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: '/',
             dataType: 'text',
             async: false
         })
  });
  </script>
```

pages.js:

```
    res.render('home', {
    pageName: "",
    userName: result[0].twitchName,
    isLive: liveStatus,
    userID: result[0].id,
    benachrichtigung: benachrichtigung,
    twitchPBUrl: twitchPBLink
  });
}
```

Thank you so much in advance :)

The best regards,
Joshy

Comment: `async: false` is a very, very bad idea. It's long deprecated, and it should be illegal in all countries.

Comment: Long story short, you are calling your server, which replies with HTML text (which is the result of the rendered EJS template). So your browser receives this HTML behind the scenes... and does nothing with it. It's not automatic, you need to treat what you receive and do something with it, update the DOM etc.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it for debugging. I miss to delete that :)

Comment: @JeremyThille Thank you for your answer, but I understood the comment of Quentin. Ajax shouldn't be used for that. I will do, that Javascript will manipulate the HTML with my response. I just have to change the response to some variables and work with them. I think that would be the cleanest way to work with that. :)

Answer (score 0):

The point of Ajax is that:

- You make an HTTP request with JS
- The response to that request is provided to JS

It **does not**:

- Render the response automatically in the browser viewport
- Travel back in time and change data that was used to create the response that the HTML document you are looking at came from

You **can**:

- Submit a `<form>` **instead of using Ajax**. The response to a form submission is rendered in the viewport (in the same way that following a link or typing a URL in the address bar is).
- Write JavaScript to use the response to update the DOM of the current page

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I understood Ajax better now. So it is not the finest way to work with Ajax like that. I will try to manipulate the html with javascript on success: from ajax. I think that should be the cleanest way :).